# Find date ranges in one table that do not overlap date ranges in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, date-range

I have two tables that each has two date fields - fromdate and todate. Using SQL Server, I need to find all of the rows from table1 that their from-to date range does not overlap the date ranges in table2. I am currently using the following

```sql
Select fromdate,
       todate
from table1
Where not exists
    (select fromdate,
            todate
     from table2
     where table1.todate > table2.fromdate
       and table1.fromdate < table2.todate)
```

However this is very slow (this is only a simplified example). Is there a better way such as using joins or CTE?

Comment: Please show some sample date and desired results.

Comment: I think that's the best way to do it, but maybe one of the SQL experts here will chime in with something that works better. I don't think a CTE will out-perform a standard Select statement. The SQL optimizer will do what it's designed to do...optimize. If performance is the issue, why not just index the tables?

Comment: You may try to add epoch index, and compare with the same function. E.g DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', todate) This should force the optimizer to use integer based index, which may be faster.

Comment: For performance issues, we need to see table and index definitions, and please share query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We can't give advice based on a "simplified example", SQL performance is too localized for that. Good indexing should work here. Side note: in an `EXISTS` subquery, it makes no difference what you select, it could just as well be `SELECT NULL`